# table rows editable - go back to original if user clicks outside the row

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and working on the editable table row, but I am stuck and needed help.

Basically, I have a table row like this below.

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>01/01/2014</td>
    <td>01/02/2014</td>
    <td>12/31/2014</td>
    <td><a id="1" class="rowEdit">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a id="1" class="rowDelete">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>02/01/2014</td>
    <td>02/02/2014</td>
    <td>12/31/2014</td>
    <td><a id="2" class="rowEdit">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a id="2" class="rowDelete">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
.... So On ...
```

and here is my Jquery when user clicks Edit.

```
$(".rowEdit").on("click", function()
{
    alert("Editing ...")
    var parentElem = $(this).parent().parent(); // get the tr
    //var tdTSID = parentElem("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdQty = parentElem.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdBeginDate = parentElem.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdEndDate = parentElem.children("td:nth-child(4)");
    var tdEdit = parentElem.children("td:nth-child(5)");
    var tdDelete = parentElem.children("td:nth-child(6)");

    tdQty.html("<input type='text' id='txtQty' value='"+ tdQty.html() +"' >")
    tdBeginDate.html("<input type='text' id='txtBeginDate' class='class_date' value='"+ tdBeginDate.html() +"' >")
    tdEndDate.html("<input type='text' id='txtEndDate' value='"+ tdEndDate.html() +"' >")

    $(".class_date").each( function()
    {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy"
        })
    })

});

$(document).click(function (e) {
        alert("Change Back to Original stage")
});
```

As you can see that when user clicks Edit, the cells in that row will change to input textboxes.  However, I couldn't figure out how to change it back when user clicks Edit on another row OR click away somewhere in the document.

Also, I am not sure if my datepicker() calendar will work correctly for another row if user click Edit on the first row, then click Edit on the second row.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try to copy the row to a hidden one (display: none)

Comment: Thanks for respond, I am sure sure how to do that?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question properly, but if you want to go back to original state, before editing, try to use cloneNode() and set display: none for it. If you want to hide the inputs of the old line, search for them using something like $('input'), get parent and change them to text. But these are only ideas... Hope it helps!

Comment: When user clicks on row# 1, the cell/column 2,3, and 4 change to textboxes for editable. User can click on any textboxes (within the TR) to edit. However, if user clicks outside the TR or elsewhere in the document, the cell#2,3, and 4 of row# 1 go back to original stage (no textboxes).  Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: So, try the second suggestion, search for inputs and change them back to text before the 'alert'.

Comment: I don't think the OP is wanting to revert the edited columns back to their original state. It sounds to me like he wants to switch the columns back to read only when the row loses focus.